# How can I parse the timestamp from my log file?

Tags: string, bash, logging, extract

I have a log file in Linux which has this type of information:

```
20200910:16:59:38 gpbackup:gpadmin:mdw:024273-[INFO]:-Starting backup of database mydb
20200910:16:59:38 gpbackup:gpadmin:mdw:024273-[INFO]:-Backup Timestamp = 20200910165938
```

I need to get the Timestamp value (20200910165938). I just need anything after the word Timestamp, the equal and the space. In the log file, there's only one occurrence of this line.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`. Print the last field (`NF`) for lines where `Timestamp` is the third field from the end (`NF-2`).

```
awk '$(NF-2)=="Timestamp" {print $NF}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'print for /Timestamp\s+=\s+(\d+)/;' logfile
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-n` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

The regex works like this:
`\s+` : 1 or more whitespace.
`\d+` : 1 or more digits.
`(\d+)` : capture 1 or more digits. If the regex matches, this "capture group" (here, timestamp) is returned by the regex as a list, and then printed. If the regex does not match, an empty list is returned, and nothing is printed.

**SEE ALSO:**

[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)

Answer (score 1):

First, let's create a test data file.

```sh
cat <<EOF > data.txt
20200910:16:59:38 gpbackup:gpadmin:mdw:024273-[INFO]:-Starting backup of database mydb
20200910:16:59:38 gpbackup:gpadmin:mdw:024273-[INFO]:-Backup Timestamp = 20200910165938
```

Now use some common unix tools to extract the timestamp.

```sh
cat data.txt | grep Timestamp | rev | cut -d' ' -f1 | rev
```

- grep - finds the right line to process.
- rev - reverses the line so that first space delimits the end of the timestamp.
- cut - extracts the reversed timestamp
- rev - flips the timestamp into the proper sequence.